# sqlite Where Like

Tags: sqlite, where-clause, sql-like

i have a small problem that i want to solve but i have some troubles. 
I a DataGrid filled with information like Name, Surname, Address, Phonenumber and Year of birth. Next to that i have a textbox that acts like a search where i search DataGrid by name. For testing i added two persons. One with name of "Mark" and second with name "1". The idea is if i type in textbox just "ma" or "mar" it should list every person whose name starts with "ma" or anything similar. 
Now the problem is, when i type the name "1"  is shows me the person whose name starts with "1" but when i type "m" for example or any other character, nothing happens. Its like only numbers work and letters don't work. What am i doing wrong, where is the problem and can someone help? Here is the query code for "FilterName":

```
   SQLiteConnection KonekcijaSQL = new 
   SQLiteConnection(@"DataSource=DzudoKlub.db;Version=3;");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        // translation to english "Select * from Person Where name Like 
        @Name + '%'"
        sb.AppendLine("SELECT * ");
        sb.AppendLine("FROM Osoba");
        if (ime != string.Empty)
        {
            sb.AppendLine("WHERE Ime like @Ime + '%'");
        }
```

Comment: Untried suggestion: Are you binding `@Ime` to the contents of the text box? If so, try appending `'%'` to the value you bind, rather than including it in the SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, `+` is used only to add numbers; string concatenation must be done with `||`.

Comment: Thanks CL. In the meantime i found a solution and changed my code a bit.

Answer (score 0):

```
        ime = ime + "%";
        SQLiteConnection KonekcijaSQL = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=DzudoKlub.db;Version=3;");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine("SELECT * ");
        sb.AppendLine("FROM Osoba");
        if (ime != string.Empty)
        {
            sb.AppendLine("WHERE Ime like  @Ime");
        }
```

.